# Access denied to /proc/mounts

Tags: linux, centos

We have centos 6.9 on a virtual machine, sometimes some process(db2sysc) has intermittent problems with access to /proc/mounts and we got the following error in the log of that process

```
FUNCTION: DB2 Common, OSSe, ossGetDiskInfo, probe:130 MESSAGE : ECF=0x90000001=-1879048191=ECF_ACCESS_DENIED Access denied CALLED : OS, -, fopen OSERR: EACCES (13) DATA #1 : String, 12 bytes /proc/mounts
```

but there are not any error messages in Syslog or kernel log(dmesg), the problem remains until we reboot the server, is there any idea for this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736613/create-tablespace-problem-in-db2-hadr-environment